# customize actionbar with tabs and buttons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabhost

I am trying to customize a action bar so that it looks like [image: link] which is an IOS liked navigation bar. Here are some articles that i found. [link1](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android) 
It seems impossible to change tabs position and size in android. i had read another stack overflow page which suggest to put a few buttons.

Is there anyway I can make such action bar with one button on the left, on button on the right and a tabs in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an awesome [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) about `Android Material Tabs`. The tutorial explains about all basic modification that can be done on `Tabs`. It also teaches to use `CustomAdapter` to build our own `Tab` style as you wanted.

Comment: hi axefox, i think you misunderstand me.i do know how to make a full screen width tabs. My problem is that filter and + are 2 separate buttons. Only News and Tops are tabs and positioned in middle

Comment: @MichaelLee Yeah, it can be implemented with the help of a custom adapter. :)